# How to use cyrillic var names in Ext.XTemplate

Tags: extjs, xtemplate

It's very necessary for me to use cyrillic names in XTemplate in ExtJs 5.1

Unfortunately this doesn't work. What I can do to solve this?

```
    // here is key-value pairs with cyrillic var names
    var varArr = [];
    varArr['key0'] = 'data';
    varArr['ключ1']= 'data'; 
    varArr['ключ2']= 'data'; 

    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('param0={key0}, param1={ключ1}, param2={ключ2}');
    
    // ключ1 and ключ2 are ignored
    document.write(tpl.apply(varArr));
```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets with values:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {

        // here is key-value pairs with cyrillic var names
        var varArr = [];
        varArr['key0'] = 'data';
        varArr['ключ1']= 'data_ключ1';
        varArr['ключ2']= 'data_ключ2';

        var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('param0={key0}, param1={[values.ключ1]}, param2={[values["ключ2"]]}');

        // ключ1 and ключ2 are ignored
        document.write(tpl.apply(varArr));


    }
});
```

Comment: Great! we can use "object" and "array" notations. Thank you!